# How can I help my succulent?

Tags: plant-health, succulents, recovery

so I think I have an Haworthia Fasciata and I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong.

[image]

I think I was over watering, so I stopped watering And put it outside for 3 days to dry out. it’s been a few weeks now without water and in this new spot. I have it by a north west facing window, getting bright light but not direct light.  It has one lil brown spot and crispy yellow tips. Is it dying?? Can I save it?!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you went a bit too extreme to the other side ;) dry tips often indicate either sun damage or underwatering. Move it to a shadier place and water it.
ps. a sign of overwatering would be yellowish leaves, which I don't think you've experienced.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same Haworthia for over 10 years now. During that time I have:

- Overwatered
- Underwatered
- Put it into too large a pot, which led to root rot
- Dumped the rotted plant out onto a garden bed in full sun

And it did not die. In fact, should you ever overwater the plant until it gets root rot, I recommend just tossing the rosettes someplace in your garden, sticking them into the soil after a couple of weeks, and then potting up whatever lives. They're an incredibly forgiving plant.

As LorDex noted, your plant isn't dead, or even hurting. The brown tips are from underwatering. Here's my regimen for my haworthia:

- East-facing window (full sun in the summer, little sun in winter)
- In late spring, summer, and up to mid-autumn, weekly watering (container must have drainage holes, with NO gravel in the bottom of the pot). Remove any water in the saucer after an hour or so.
- In winter, water once every two weeks.

My experience is that too large of a pot always leads to root rot, so I keep my plants in small, shallow pots. You'll know you're doing things right when your plant puts out offsets.